# Gamma distribution in python

Tags: python, r, excel, gamma-distribution

We have `qgamma` in R and `gamm.inv` in excel, and I am not able to get the same results using `invgamma` function in python. For example in excel
`GAMMA.INV(0.99,35,0.08)=4.01`, I can get the same value from R using `qgamma` with `probability=0.99, alpha(scale)=35.0, shape=0.08`.

But when I am using `invgamma.pdf(0.99,35,0.8)` it returns `1.61787636512e-15`.

What is the right way of doing it? I have tried both `gamma` and `invgamma` with `pdf`, `ppf`, `cdf` but nothing is matching with the value I am getting from `qgamma` in R or `GAMMA.INV` in excel

Comment: [I can't reproduce the results you say you're getting in R.](https://ideone.com/EpT4OS)

Comment: Can you get the value in excel? I checked in R and it was matching with excel values. Will provide the  exact arguments used in R by evening

Answer (score 6):

`qgamma` and `GAMMA.INV` give the [*inverse cumulative distribution function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_function) of a [*gamma distribution*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution).

`invgamma` represents an [*inverse gamma distribution*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-gamma_distribution), which is a completely different thing. Explaining the difference is out of scope for this site, as it's a statistics issue, not a programming issue, but you should really get it solidly understood before you proceed.

The SciPy distribution object for a gamma distribution is [`scipy.stats.gamma`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gamma.html#scipy.stats.gamma), and the method for the inverse cumulative distribution function is [`ppf`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.ppf.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous.ppf), short for "percentile point function" (another name for the inverse CDF). Thus, you should be using `scipy.stats.gamma.ppf`. Make sure to pass it the right arguments.

Comment: Thanks for clarification on invgamma, but when I am using scipy.stats.gamma.ppf(0.99,35,0.08)=50.29 it's not matching with excel gammainv(0.99,35,0.08)=4.01

Comment: @SKD: `gamma.ppf` doesn't take the same arguments as `gammainv`. You're passing `loc` instead of `scale`. You also appear to be mixing up scale and shape in general; alpha is the shape parameter, not the scale.

Comment: yes I am sure I am doing something wrong, can you guide me what should  be the argument to get  the  value same as excel

Comment: Ok got the  right argument it's gamma.ppf(0.99,35,0,0.08). I have to pass loc as 0 between shape and scale. Thanks a lot user2357112

Comment: For some reason, beta.ppf and gamma.ppf have different argument orders; in gamma, the location comes in between the shape & scale, but it is after in beta. This threw me for a loop until I found this thread.